# Problems passing this wrapped in a smart pointer to a method in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, this, listener, smart-pointers

I have 2 classes that depends on each other (cyclic dependency). One is just an object `Person` and the other listens to changes on the object `PersonListener`. The `Person` class is defined as follows.

```
class Person {
 private:
  std::string name;
  PersonListener listener;
 public:
  Person(std::string name, PersonListener listener) : name{name}, listener{listener} {};
  void setName(std::string name) {
   this->name = name;
   auto sPointer = std::make_shared<Person>(*this); // problem here? makes a copy?
   listener.nameChanged(sPointer); // how do I pass this by reference?
  }
}
```

The `PersonListener` is defined as follows.

```
class PersonListener {
 public:
  PersonListener() {}
  void nameChanged(std::shared_ptr<Person> person) {
    std::cout << "changed" << std::endl;
    // some mutation to person would occur here
    // the way I am passing this of the Person does not allow me to reflect mutations
  }
};
```

The problem is with passing `this` of the `Person` instance to `PersonListener`. When `PersonListener` mutates the passed in shared pointer, the changes are not reflected.

A current workaround I have is to overload `PersonListener.nameChanged` to `void nameChanged(Person *person)` using a raw pointer. This approach is fine, but that introduces awkwardness in that I am using smart pointers nearly everywhere and then here, a raw one (note that in my real example, passing in a raw pointer also has implications elsewhere in the code).

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: what do you expect this line to do? `auto sPointer = std::make_shared<Person>(*this);`

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> auto sPointer = std::make_shared<Person>(*this); // problem here? makes a copy?
> ```

Yes, it does.

It's tempting to think of using

```
listener.nameChanged(std::shared_ptr<Person>(this));
```

but then, `this` becomes the managed object of the `shared_ptr`, which is not right.

I don't see any reason why you cannot use

```
class PersonListener {
    ...
    void nameChanged(Person& person) { ... }
};
```

and call it with

```
listener.nameChanged(*this)
```

#### Update, in response to OP's comment

If you must use a `shared_ptr`, you can use a noop deleter when constructing the `shared_ptr`.

```
std::shared_ptr<Person> sPointer(this, [](Person* ptr) {});
//                                     ^^ The deleter. It doesn't do anything.
listener.nameChanged(sPointer);
```

Comment: That is fine too, except that the listener will call other methods that is expecting a `shared_ptr`. Which, leads me to overloading the method signature between either `shared_ptr` and `raw pointer` or `shared_ptr` and `pass-by-reference`. It seems I cannot get away with method overloading.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen, good catch. It sure does. Let me think of a better suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
auto sPointer = std::make_shared<Person>(*this); // problem here? makes a copy?
```

Yes, `std::make_shared` **always** creates a new object. In this case, it calls copy constructor of `Person` and creates a new one, which then it can manage.

---

It's difficult to suggest something without context. Probably the best solution was provided by R Sahu in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60442471/7976805), but it could be done without modyfying `PersonListener` interface.

---

One thing would be to use regular `std::shared_ptr` constructor while providing a none-deleter:

```
auto sPointer = std::shared_ptr<Person>(this, [](auto){}); //custom deleter which does nothing to the object owned
```

This solution is probably going to confuse people - why use `shared_ptr` when it doesn't manage anything? On the other hand, use of `this` might be a clue why that was done.

---

If you want to be able to get a functional `shared_ptr` from inside of the class, you can also consider [`enable_shared_from_this`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this).

```
class Person: public std::enable_shared_from_this<Person> {
 private:
  std::string name;
  PersonListener listener;
 public:
  Person(std::string name, PersonListener listener) : name{name}, listener{listener} {};
  void setName(std::string name) {
   this->name = name;
   auto sPointer = shared_from_this(); //get a shared_ptr to this
   listener.nameChanged(sPointer); 
  }
}
```

Note that this approach has quite a few disadvantages:

- Objects of `Person` class *always* have to be created as `std::shared_ptr` (so you cannot do e.g. `Person myPerson;` anywhere)
- You cannot call `shared_from_this()` in constructor, because the parent `shared_ptr` does not exist yet.
- It can easily lead to circular dependencies and memory leaks which are not detectable with many tools (like `valgrind`). If `PersonListener` will store the pointer it received as its member, neither of the objects will be deleted.

Comment: In the example I gave, I should have overloaded the `ctor` (one with and one without `PersonListener`). The `Person` object may or may not have a listener injected (mind you, my mothership is Java).

Comment: @JaneWayne That doesn't change my answer (but it's quite late, so I might be overlooking something). Things that may be strange for Java programmer: `listener` is a copy of the listener provided in constructor and it's not polymorphic (if you plan on injecting some derived classes this way, it will not work - `listener` is always `PersonListener` and nothing else)